# How to make interactive OpenStreetMap layers in TileMill?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill, utfgrid, unique-id

If I'm reading the [UTFGrid spec](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec/blob/master/1.3/utfgrid.md) right, you can only have 65,501 different interactive features. Or more precisely, every feature needs a unique ID in the range 0-65501.

TileMill uses UTFGrid for its interactivity, so this limit seems to apply. It shows up as non-parseable JSON being generated, JSON handling exceptions etc.

So, what ID can you use for OpenStreetMap features (loaded into a PostGIS database), given that the `osm_id` column will have values in the hundreds of millions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a unique id per row it will be easiest to use the [row number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

```
 SELECT (row_number() OVER())-1 AS id, way, (...)
```

That way you'll get incrementing id starting from 0 and won't have to worry about collision.

Comment: Well, sure, but that only works if you want the right solution, instead of my hacky workaround. Dammit. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple workaround that seems to work ok. Make a PostGIS layer with an extra column like this:

```
(SELECT way,....
osm_id % 65500 AS tinyid
FROM planet_osm_point) p
```

Then set `tinyid` as the layer's "Unique key field".

That is, take the actual `osm_id` modulo 65500 to always produce a value in the range 0-65500. This will occasionally cause errors if two features within the same tile have the same `tinyid`.

(There might be better ways?)